# What is the reason for mode collapse in GAN as opposed to WGAN?

Tags: neural-networks, generative-adversarial-networks, kl-divergence, wasserstein-metric, wasserstein-gan

[In this article](https://lilianweng.github.io/lil-log/2017/08/20/from-GAN-to-WGAN.html) I am reading:

> $D_{KL}$ gives us inifity when two distributions are disjoint. The value of $D_{JS}$ has sudden jump, not differentiable at $\theta=0$. Only Wasserstein metric provides a smooth measure, which is super helpful for a stable learning process using gradient descents.

Why is this important for a stable learning process? I have also the feeling this is also the reason for mode collapse in GANs, but I am not sure.

The Wasserstein GAN paper also talks about it obviously, but I think I am missing a point. Does it say JS does not provide a usable gradient? What exactly does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a definite answer, but only a suspicion/idea:

Looking at Figure 1 from the [WGAN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.07875.pdf), we clear see that the JS divergence on the right is not continuous at $0$, hence not differentiable at $0$. However, the EM plot on the left is continuous also at $0$. You could now argue that we have a kink there, so it should not be differentiable there either, but they might have a different notion of differentiability, I am honestly not sure about it right now.  [image]

Comment: There is a fairly straightforward way of doing optimization of piecewise linear functions that would deal fine with the left hand side, the non-differentiability at the 'kink' is not an issue, see e.g. [here](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/ee236a/lectures/pwl.pdf)